# cython dict access results in segmentation fault

Tags: python, caching, cython, unordered-map

I am trying to implement a simple cached method in cython. The compilation went through but read cache at run time crashes the program with segmentation fault.

Here is my cython `hello.pyx` file

```
# disutils: language = C++
# define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
cimport libc.stdint
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
from libc.stdio cimport printf
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map
from libcpp.pair cimport pair
from cython.operator cimport dereference

np.import_array()  # needed to initialize numpy-API

cdef class DemoClass:
    cdef readonly unordered_map[double, double[:]] cache

    def __init__(self):
        cdef unordered_map[double, double[:]] cache
        self.cache = cache

    cpdef double[:] demoMethod(self, double key):

        if self.cache.count(key) > 0:
            printf("second time")
            return self.cache[key]

        printf("First time")
        cdef double[:] result = cnp_empty(100)
        self.cache[key] = result

        return result
```

and here is what I tried to run in python

```
from hello import DemoClass

import numpy as np
demoObj2 = DemoClass()
print(demoObj2.demoMethod(0.0)) # <MemoryView of 'ndarray' object>
print(demoObj2.demoMethod(0.0)) # this results in Segmentation fault, no more messages
```

Which bit about the unordered map am I using wrong?

---

Edit: David's answer inspired me to try something else

```
from hello import DemoClass

import numpy as np
demoObj2 = DemoClass()
a = demoObj2.demoMethod(0.0)
print(a) # <MemoryView of 'ndarray' object>
print(demoObj2.demoMethod(0.0)) # this works fine now, because the reference to the memoryview is now kept, in python.
```

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** store a memoryview in an unordered map. A memoryview is a Cython-managed reference-counted type and the C++ unordered map doesn't know about the reference counting or initialization of the memoryview.

The Cython 3.0 alpha will diagnose this and emit an error message to stop you from doing it. But older versions of Cython won't.

An unordered map is not suitable for what you're aiming to do. A Python dict would be better (although it stores an "untyped" Python wrapper of the memoryview, so isn't ideal for speed). However, realistically you're probably better storing the raw Numpy arrays in the dict rather than the memoryviews of those arrays.

Comment: Thank you David. If I only intend for the result of demoMethod to be used by the cython/C api, is there a way of using the typed unordered map instead of dict? Would it be sensible to have a map[float, C array/vector] for caching, and then convert the array to memoryview when needed for py?

Comment: You could definitely use a map of a vector. Not a map of a C array I think.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @DavidW, once the result `memoryview` is returned, if there is no python code which references it, python will do garbage-cleaning on the object, causing the cache to point to deleted data.

AFAIK, There are two ways to work around this.

1. Use `from cpython.ref cimport Py_INCREF` to `Py_INCREF` to manually increase python reference to the memoryview `result` when caching. This means GIL is acquired.
2. Instead of using memory_view, use libcpp.vector. This is not garbage-cleaned by python, so it doesn't need the reference inc and can be done without the gil.